# Can you solve the following equation by moving exactly 3 matchsticks?

Tags: mathematics, matches

If yes, how? (every line is a matchstick)

```
+---------        |       |        |                 +---------+
|                 |       |        |                 |         |
|                 |       |        |   -----------   |         |
+--------+   -----+-----  +--------+                 +---------+
         |        |                |   -----------   |         |
         |        |                |                 |         |
---------+        |                |                 +---------+
```

Rules:

- There is space beyond the edges, they don't wrap.
- Although this isn't tagged [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), out-of-the-box thoughts are welcome as well.

Comment: I really want many answers, really. It's not a problem here, Emrakul.

Comment: If you're looking for many answers, that suggests that the question really is too broad.

Comment: @Emrakul I.e. many out-of-the-box thoughts. Also, it's not a usual Q&A site here, so I thought of letting people answer their own way.

Comment: Questions still need to have a sufficiently limited range of answers to be a good fit for Puzzling. Incorrect guesses are fine - it's when a large number of answers fit the question that it becomes a problem.

Comment: @Emrakul Move 3 matches, that's all. No 2 matches, no 4 matches! 3, and only 3!

Comment: I think I've counted at least 4 or 5 honest answers (not move 2 or 4).

Comment: @WernerCD The first is accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 15 - 7 = 8
>
>  Where the 7 is the sort where the top-left vertical is present.
>
>  Move the *two* vertical matches of the + to make a 1 to the left of the 5. And move the 4's *one* horizontal upwards to make the 7's top horizontal. So I move 3 matches.
> Visualization:
> `. +---------        A       |        |                 +---------+`
> `. |                 A       |        |                 |         |`
> `. |                 A       |        |   -----------   |         |`
> `. +--------+   -----+-----  +CCCCCCCC+                 +---------+`
> `.          |        B                |   -----------   |         |`
> `.          |        B                |                 |         |`
> `. ---------+        B                |                 +---------+`
> Becomes: 
> `. A   +---------                 +CCCCCCCC+                 +---------+`
> `. A   |                          |        |                 |         |`
> `. A   |                          |        |   -----------   |         |`
> `. +   +--------+   -----------   |        +                 +---------+`
> `. B            |                          |   -----------   |         |`
> `. B            |                          |                 |         |`
> `. B   ---------+                          |                 +---------+`

Comment: Re-accepted, I now realized this is the first correct one.

Comment: This answer is not correct. 7 does not wrap around like that on a digital screen.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It's not a seven-segment display default 7, but the puzzle did not ask for the numbers to follow the seven-segment display default numbers.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I've seen 7s displayed like that on 7-segment displays before.

Comment: I edited the answer to add visualization, but in the review section for the edit, the "rendered output" looks like the ASCII art doesn't line up, however looking at my edit here, it does line up perfectly.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck and Deusovi So have I.

Comment: @SpiritFryer Looks fine to me. My inbox got a message "edit suggested" re your edit. It wasn't clear what I should do in order to accept it -- does SE accept the edit by default, seeing as I won't roll it back?

Comment: @RosieF It seems to have gone through. I am not sure how it works exactly, I think people with enough points can accept edits too, not just the owner, so maybe that's what happened.

Answer (score 24):

Here's how I would do it:

> 5 + 0 = 5.  Take two sticks from the 8, give them to the 4, and move one of the 4's sticks to turn it into a 0.

Comment: This answer seems more correct than the other.

Comment: This answer doesn't rely on ambiguity or niche facts like a nonstandard 7SD. Much better, should be accepted.

Comment: It might seem to be an obvious answer, and we must **not** forget "[Simple is better than complex...](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)" :)

Answer (score 8):

I can do it in one.

$5 + 4 \equiv 9$

**Edit**: Because there appears to be a discussion going on in the comments of this answer, I have moved my comment up here:

> If you want me to move three sticks, then pick up any two matchsticks and swap them.

Comment: Brilliant! +1 good job

Comment: This question asks for the case iff 3 matchsticks are moved. This does not answer the question.

Comment: If you nudge the two sticks that form the `=` up a little, and add the third one below them, you have moved three.

Comment: @PeregrineRook Nope, LaTeX is not your advisor here. The equal sign *can* be nudged, if there is no reason specified in the answer.

Comment: If you want me to move three sticks, then pick up any two matchsticks and swap them.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: I have no idea what you're saying (although I suppose my comment was not 100% clear, either).  I was responding to MarchHo's comment, suggesting that, while Ian is *claiming* a one-match solution, $5+4 \equiv 9$ can easily (and yet ***non-trivially***) be implemented as a three-match answer (thus satisfying the constraint in the question).

Comment: @PeregrineRook It *was* clear to me: I just said that the $=$ lines can be alerady nudged a bit, before you move any match.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: Alas, I still do not understand what you are saying.  (For example, why do you mention LaTeX in your first comment to me?)

Comment: @PeregrineRook Because LaTeX nudges differently on the two symbols.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my solution:

> Turn `5 + 4 = 8` into `9 - 9 = 0`, by moving two matchsticks from the plus sign and one from the number eight.
>  Visualization:
> `. +---------        A       |        |                 +---------+`
> `. |                 A       |        |                 |         |`
> `. |                 A       |        |   -----------   |         |`
> `. +--------+   -----+-----  +--------+                 +CCCCCCCCC+`
> `.          |        B                |   -----------   |         |`
> `.          |        B                |                 |         |`
> `. ---------+        B                |                 +---------+`
> Becomes:
> `. +--------+                +BBBBBBBB+                 +---------+`
> `. |        A                |        |                 |         |`
> `. |        A                |        |   -----------   |         |`
> `. +--------+   -----------  +--------+                 +         +`
> `.          |                         |   -----------   |         |`
> `.          |                         |                 |         |`
> `. ---------+                CCCCCCCCC+                 +---------+`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution by moving **two** matchsticks. (*By the way, after having come up with this solution I realized that the puzzle asks for the movement of exactly **three** matchsticks rather than two, so I'll keep thinking.*)

> Change 5 + 4 = 8 to 5 + 4 > 8
>  You do this by changing the angle of the two matchsticks making up the = sign so that they make a > sign.

Comment: The three are not *that* simple :)

Comment: Besides, since the question title says "Can you solve the following equation ...", an answer that is *not an equation* might be seen as being out of bounds.

Comment: Well, either way, you can see my actual (legal) answer above this one (or below if this had gotten voted higher over time). I just thought this was a cool solution despite not following the instructions, so I won't delete it. And as I said in the text above, originally I had thought the question only asked for the movement of two matchsticks, not three. I only realized it required three once I had finished writing this solution up. Edit: Forgot to @ you, oh well. @PeregrineRook

Comment: @SpiritFryer Just a reminder on @ mentions: The last commenter and the author will be notified, if you don't supply any @. If you supply an @, the author and previous commenters having the same first 3 characters as in the @ will be notified (not necessarily the last commenter) (`@abcd` will notify abcd and abce and abc, if they were previous commenters). You can also *sometimes* notify only the author with this notation.

Answer (score 2):

I can do it in 4.

> Move the top left of the 4, to bottom left of 5, making a 6.
>  Move the horizontal bar of the 4 up, making a 7.
>  Move the two left verticals of the 8 to the left, Making it 13.

Comment: Nice one, but you need to do it in 3 movements, not 2.

Comment: Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out.

Comment: @WernerCD Are you trying to learn some kind of Old English here??? Anyways, I think some people will have trouble understanding your comment (You mustn't count 4 or 2, you must count 3. Five is right out.)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOrgLj9lOwk  Skip ahead to 48 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Another answer:

> 15 - 9 = 6

From

> `. +---------        |       |        |                 +---------+`
> `. |                 1       |        |                 |         |`
> `. |                 |       |        |   -----------   |         3`
> `. +--------+   -----+-----  +--------+                 +---------+`
> `.          |        |                |   -----------   |         |`
> `.          |        2                |                 |         |`
> `. ---------+        |                |                 +---------+`
>
> becomes
>
> `. +  +---------                +---3----+                 +---------+`
> `. 1  |                         |        |                 |`
> `. |  |                         |        |   -----------   |`
> `. +  +--------+   -----+-----  +--------+                 +---------+`
> `. |           |                         |   -----------   |         |`
> `. 2           |                         |                 |         |`
> `. +  ---------+                         |                 +---------+`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple:

> 9 - 3 = 6
>  Vertical match from + sign goes to 5 to create 9.
>  Left vertical match from 4 is placed horizontally on top to make it more like 3.
>  Top right vertical match from 8 is placed on the bottom of ex-4 to make it a 3.

Comment: The plus sign is 4 matches, not 2.

Comment: If someone downvoted that, I would like to know why.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Hmm. I could see the reasoning behind that, though, in my opinion, in the original post it looks more like 3, not 4.

Comment: I originally thought the plus sign was made with 2 matches instead of 4 as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
+------         |         ------+             +-------+
|               |               |    ------   |       |
+-----+    -----+-----    ------+    ------   +-------+
|     |         |               |                     |
+-----+         |         ------+                     |
```

Answer (score 1):

> Change 5 to 0 by removing the middle horizontal match down vertically and removing the 4's horizontal match to add it to right bottom side it to close it to 0.
>  Move the right vertical match of 4 to leave it as 1.  add it to = in a crossed pattern.
> $$0+1 \not=8$$

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it to hide the text.

Comment: I added them for you, but you'll need to accept the edit. You do it by adding a >! at the start of each line that you want to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
+---------                +--------+                 +---------+
|                                  |                           |
|                                  |   -----------             |
+--------+   -----+-----  +--------+                 +---------+
|        |                         |   -----------             |
|        |                         |                           |
+--------+                ---------+                 +---------+
```